# Positive vs Negative HCF of Compound Algebraic Expressions

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I was learning to find the Highest Common Factor of two compound algebraic expressions using the long division method. However, I encountered the following question which puzzled me to a great extent:

Find the HCF of : *$x^3$ - $x^2$ - 5x - 3* and *$x^3$ - 4$x^2$ - 11x - 6*

On examining the two expressions to find there is not simple factor, we divide *$x^3$ - 4$x^2$ - 11x - 6* by *$x^3$ - $x^2$ - 5x - 3*

Omitting the steps of division, we obtain the remainder : -3$x^2$ - 6x - 3

Further inspecting the remainder, we break it down into simple factors: *-3($x^2$ + 2x + 1)*

Since the two original expressions had no simple factors, we can safely say that the HCF will also not consist of a simple factor. Now, remembering that every remainder contains the HCF, we reject our simple factor i.e *-3* and continue on with *$x^2$ + 2x + 1*

Making the remainder as our next divisor and our previous divisor as our next dividend, proceed with the division: $\dfrac{$x^3$ - $x^2$ - 5x - 3}{$x^2$ + 2x + 1}$

The remainder thus obtained is : -3$x^2$ - 6x - 3

Again we separate simple factors from it to obtain : -3($x^2$ + 2x + 1 ) --------- (1)

Rejecting the simple factor and considering  *$x^2$ + 2x + 1*, we get our new divisor as *$x^2$ + 2x + 1* and new dividend (previous divisor) as *$x^2$ + 2x + 1*

Clearly, they will divide each other and the remainder will be 0. This, thus states that the expression *$x^2$ + 2x + 1* is HCF of the two original expressions.


However, now take a look back: We resolved the remainder into the simple factor i.e *-3* [as explained in (1)], but we could also have resolved into: *3 (-$x^2$ - 2x - 1 )*

Now, lets continue with this as the remainder

We reject the simple factor and consider  *(-$x^2$ - 2x - 1 )* as our divisor.
So, the nex dividend becomes: *$x^2$ + 2x + 1*.

Clearly, they will divide each other and the HCF in this case would come out to be : *(-$x^2$ - 2x - 1 )*

Since two expressions can have only one highest common factors, which one is it here? Is it *(-$x^2$ - 2x - 1 )* or ($x^2$ + 2x + 1 )* ?